# Error while compiling a function

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix

[image: error screenshot]Below function is showing error while compilation that "stack is too deep, try removing local variables

```
 mapping (address => mapping (uint => Exam)) public exams;
 function getExamQuestion(
    uint _eid, 
    uint _topic_id, 
    address _university, 
    uint _sno,
    uint _examkey,
    uint lastQid
) onlyStudent constant returns (string _quhash) {
    Exam storage e = exams[_university][_eid];
    require(
        e.active 
        && e.starttime <= now 
        && e.endtime > now
        && enroll[_university][_eid][msg.sender]
    );
```

}